# How to use regular expression for client side verification of entries using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

This javascript code is working until the regular expression is used to evaluate the entries in client side verification through javascript. Please check the regular expressions and get me a solution that can check the entries by checking through regular expressions.
Here I am attaching the code to evaluate. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var tuname=document.forms["teachersignup"]["tusername"];
            var tname=document.forms["teachersignup"]["tname"];
            var temail=document.forms["teachersignup"]["temail"];
            var tpassword=document.forms["teachersignup"]["tpassword"];
            var tiname=document.forms["teachersignup"]["tiname"];

            var uname=document.getElementById("uname");
            var naame=document.getElementById("nname");
            var email=document.getElementById("email");
            var pswd=document.getElementById("password");
            var iname=document.getElementById("iname");

            tuname.addEventListener("blur",unameVerify,true);
            tname.addEventListener("blur",nameVerify,true);
            temail.addEventListener("blur",emailVerify,true);
            tpassword.addEventListener("blur",passwordVerify,true);
            tiname.addEventListener("blur",inameVerify,true);

            var ck_password =  /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{8,30}$/;
            var ck_iname = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*{3,60}$/;
            var ck_username = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_@]{3,20}$/;
            var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z]{3,60}$/;
            var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;


            function ValidateForm(){
                if(tuname.value == "" ){
                    tuname.style.border="1px solid red";
                    uname.innerHTML="Enter a valid username";
                    tuname.focus();
                    return false;   
                }
                if(tname.value == "" ){
                    tname.style.border="1px solid red";
                    naame.innerHTML="Enter a valid name";
                    tname.focus();
                    return false;   
                }
                if(temail.value == "" ){
                    temail.style.border="1px solid red";
                    email.innerHTML="Enter a valid email";
                    temail.focus();
                    return false;   
                }
                if(tpassword.value == "" ){
                    tpassword.style.border="1px solid red";
                    pswd.innerHTML="Enter a valid password";
                    tuname.focus();
                    return false;   
                }
                if(tiname.value == "" ){
                    tiname.style.border="1px solid red";
                    iname.innerHTML="Enter a valid institute's name";
                    tuname.focus();
                    return false;   
                }
            }
            function unameVerify(){
                if(tuname.value!=""){
                    tuname.style.border="1px solid #5bc0de";
                    uname.innerHTML="";
                    return true;

                }

            }
            function nameVerify(){
                if(tname.value!=""  ){

                    tname.style.border="1px solid #5bc0de";
                    name.innerHTML="";
                    return true;
                }

            }
            function emailVerify(){
                if(temail.value!="" ){
                    temail.style.border="1px solid #5bc0de";
                    email.innerHTML="";
                    return true;
                }

            }
            function passwordVerify(){
                if(tpassword.value!=""){
                    tpassword.style.border="1px solid #5bc0de";
                    pswd.innerHTML="";
                    return true;
                }

            }
            function inameVerify(){
                if(tiname.value!="" ){
                    tiname.style.border="1px solid #5bc0de";
                    iname.innerHTML="";
                    return true;
                }

            }

    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed description of what is not working about your code.

Comment: If I am using the regular expressions for evaluation in conditional statements then it is not working.
So where to place the regular expressions for evaluation of entries in client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

`var tuname_val = tuname.value;`

`var valid_tuname = tuname_val.match(ck_username);`

This will return an object having a key *'input'* that will store valid input that matched your pattern.

Tell me if this didn't work.

Comment: What will this return?
And how to use this as conditions for.
For eg if the entries doesn't satisfy then it will not move to next page. It mush show a message of error in the same registration page

Comment: please suggest me how to approach?

Comment: I have created JSFiddle for this. Have a look at it here: https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/pmh90571/
On line 127 of JS, you can add script to alert user that the password length must be min 8 & max 30, instead of saying 'Not a valid password' (as I have done in the fiddle). Also, the regex ck_iname had some errors, so I have used ck_name for it instead. 
Check and tell if it helped.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help